# Securely delivering important in game content on start up

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase

Okay, here is the deal:

User's can buy 'gold' inside of the app with in-app billing.  In order to make sure nobody cheats the system, I don't want to store the amount of gold a person has on phone.  I already need to contact the server on start up so I figure I can send the amount of gold a user has at that time.  However, I cannot think of a way to make this 'secure'(ie, how can I prevent a user from faking the server response and giving themselves gold).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution here would be to deploy mutually-authenticated SSL between your game and your server. You can use self-signed certificates here so you don't need to buy any from a CA. This will ensure that your game only receives balance information from your legitimate server (configure the SSL system for your game to only accept the self-signed certificate that your server is using) and your server only accepts queries from your game (configure your server to only access the self-signed certificate deployed in your app as a resource for client authentication). There is a complete step-by-step rundown on how to do this for Android in [Application Security for the Android Platform](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do), published by O'Reilly.

Comment: Whomever wrote that book is great ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could "sign" the response with a signature (probably based on the amount of gold, a user and a timestamp) generated by a private/public key pair. That way you can verify in your client that the responses are actually coming from your server. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it a problem if someone fakes a response from the server?  They're only fooling themselves about how much gold they have; the real server still knows the real number.

Unless your server will later *ask* the client how much gold it has and trust the answer it gets, this shouldn't be a problem.  The server should always have the authoritative value.